# MonkeyTalk error report to a .txt/excel file

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, monkeytalk

I am trying to write some test scripts to test an app for IOS devices.  I would like to report each error in a text excel file.  I have written the following code (using JavaScript in the MonkyTalkIDE):

> var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
>      var s = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\\test.txt");
>      s.WriteLine('Hello');
>      s.Close();

If I embed the code above in a html-file it works as expected. Does anyone have a solution for this problem or can anyone give me the reason why this is not working in combination with MonkeyTalk?

Answer (score 1):

This code won't work in MonkeyTalk as it requires ActiveXObjects, which MonkeyTalk does not support - ActiveX is specific to Internet Explorer.

However, if you want custom `verify` messages it is possible like this:

```
this.app.view("monkeyid").verify("expected", "property", "custom message"); --JavaScript
View monkeyid Verify expected property "custom message" --MonkeyTalk
```

The the default property is `value`.